# Idealized Plot of two overlapping distributions with different skewness?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, probability

In order to show the effect of increasing right skewness I want to create two overlapping plots where one distribution is more right skewed than the other.

So I do something like the following

```
library(SuppDists)

tmp1fun <- function(m1=0,m2=1,m3=-0.2,m4=3.7,n=20000) {
    parms <- JohnsonFit(c(m1,m2,m3,m4), 'use')
    rJohnson(n,parms) }

data1.dens <- rbind(data.frame(var1=rep('now',50000),y=tmp1fun(m3=-0.2,n=50000))
    ,data.frame(var1=rep('hist',50000),y=tmp1fun(m3=0.2,n=50000)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1.dens, aes(y, fill = var1))+
geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-4, 4))
```

However it doesn't look right, it looks more like the mean of the distribution is shifted with regards to the other. Also I'd kind of like the density plot to look a bit smoother.

So my question has two parts
1. What distribution and what parameters should I use so that one distribution looks similar to the other, but just more right skewed?
2. What is the best graphics tool for producing this plot? If possible I'd like a filled chart rather than just a line, and perhaps a higher bandwidth with the smoother.

Thanks for any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to show theoretical densities using the *actual* probability density function, and not just random variates with a smoother. Especially when the distribution is long-tailed, because it could take a huge number of random variates to accurately characterize the tail. The probability density function will also (obviously) result in a smoother density.

Playing with the density function should make it rather apparent which parameter does what. Here I change `m1`, which results in the shape that you are asking for.

Here is an option that parallels your example, using the probability density function and `geom_polygon()`:

```
library(SuppDists)
library(ggplot2)
# function to calculate density along a grid
JohnsonDensity = function(m1 = 0, m2 = 1, m3 = -0.2, m4 = 3.7, n = 10000) {
    parms <- JohnsonFit(c(m1, m2, m3, m4))
    J_quantiles = na.omit(qJohnson(seq(0, 1, length.out = n+2), parms))
    J_pdf = dJohnson(J_quantiles, parms)
    return( data.frame(pdf = c(J_pdf, 0, 0), x = c(J_quantiles, J_quantiles[length(J_quantiles)], J_quantiles[1]) ) )
}

# values of the pdf along the grid for two distributions
data_density = rbind(data.frame(var1 = "now", JohnsonDensity() ), data.frame(var1 = "hist", JohnsonDensity(m1 = 0.2)) )

ggplot(data_density, aes(x = x, y = pdf, color = var1, fill = var1)) + geom_polygon(alpha = 0.5)
```

In this example, the smoothness of the density is controlled by `n`, which is now the number of grid points along which the density will be calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason though the plots look quite different to the original ones ? Do you have any suggestions about why that is ? Thanks.

Comment: I imagine this is because the distribution has a very long tail. So even with 50,000 random variates, you were not able to accurately characterize the tail. Remember, the variates will be clustered around the mode of the distribution.